# Deleted my project by reset HARD or clear - github-mac

Tags: git, github, git-detached-head

Im soo gaddem stupid, I need some help here.

I was trying to get my project to Github and i created a repo in github.
Then i did git clone ........git and after a few tryes, my project was gone.

I had some problems doign "git add ..." becouse "everything" on my mac was include, saw it when did git status. So i tryed to clear my git status.
The command i did were

- git reset --HARD
- git checkout
- git clear
- git clear -xdf
- git clear -d

So buttom line is, where my project was, there is only the readme file from github after all this stupid things.

How can i undo this change and get my project back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git log
```

Find a commit where you want to continue from.

```
git checkout <revision_id> .
```

The dot means to apply the changes to the entire tree, you need this. After that, commit the changes, and continue as usual.

Comment: The problem is that i never got to adding or committing there is nothing in the log. So i guess this is a local problem, but thanks!

Comment: In that case, git can't reverse what you did, there's a reason why --HARD is spelt that way. If there's not much work, you'll have to do it over again, if there is, I suggest you try to recover your files with some deleted file recovery tool.